# Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False} for Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, options

I'm aware of two ways to manage positioning of `Axes` for `Graphics3D`: `AxesOrigin` and `AxesEdge`. They seem to be quite different in terms of what is actually happening:

```
GraphicsRow[{
             Graphics3D[##, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}], 
             Graphics3D[##, AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, {-1, -1}}]
            } &[Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 1], Axes -> True, ViewPoint -> {5, 7, 3}]]
```

[image]

**I want the graphics elements to be up front**.

For axes being a part of the box it is natural to use `AxesEdge` since it gives me that effect.

However sometimes I want the axes origin to be inside the box. `AxesEdge` is useless and `AxesOrigin` creates strange effect:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity@1, Sphere[{1, 1, 1}, 1]}, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

Axes created with `AxesOrigin` seem to be different object than with `AxesEdge`. It looks like some kind of **2D projection in front of 3D graphics** while `AxesEdge` creates something which is **part of 3D graphics**.

As one may know there ([..find undocumented options...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/5478)) is an undocumented option `Method -> { "AxesInFront" -> False }` to deal with this issue in $2D$ graphics.

It doesn't seem to work in $3D$. **So my question is** if anyone is aware of, maybe undocumented, **option** responsible for that.

If this is a projection it could be behind the `Graphics3D` objects too, couldn't it be? (*that's a little bit naive, in form, question since I do not know much about graphics rendering etc*)

---

P.s. I do not expect answers like "You can use `FindDivisions`+`Line`" etc. I'm looking for simple and fast solution. Or an answer that there isn't any. (*spelunking appreciated too:)*)

Comment: fyi, I do not get the same image in your first draw. I get this ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DzlaS.png)  (on winows 7, V 9.01)

Comment: @Nasser done. try now.

Comment: *spelnuking* - is that when you nuke your spelling?

Comment: @SimonWoods ehh. one could just check my posts looking for funny typos and it would be all week long game :P Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Arrows on axes in Plot3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2785/245)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, in the case of your sphere you'd like the sphere to obscure your axes and ticks, except perhaps for a little bit where they poke out at the edges.

This isn't currently possible without writing your own axes using `Line` and `Inset`.

The `"AxesInFront"` and other `"...InFront"` method options only apply to `Graphics` which doesn't have a natural $z$-order.

Comment: Hello, I believe we haven't talk ever before. Ok, judging by you profile it seems to be a final answer. :) But let me ask you about some detailas or the refference about my thoughts about nature of axes in graphics3D, do not leave me with only intuitive understanding. :)

Comment: And yes, you understand correctly. Also, forgive me my curiosity, but the fact you have written ""AxesInFront" and other "...InFront" options", while here we are aware of only `Axes` and `GridLines`, 'forces' me to ask about some 'other' examples :)

Comment: There's also "FrameInFront" but you're much less likely to run into cases where it might be useful.