# Hiding axis ticks and labels in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, bugs, labeling, ticks

This code:

```
arrowAxes[arrowLength_] := 
  Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]]} &, arrowLength IdentityMatrix[3]];

Graphics3D[
  {Sphere[{1, 1, 1}], arrowAxes[3]},
  Axes -> True,
  Boxed -> False, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
  AxesStyle -> Opacity[0], 
  TicksStyle -> Opacity[1]]
```

will produce these plots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How not to display tick and labels that are behind the sphere? *(this is the case in the first and second picture above; third picture is correct in that sense, since blue axis is in front of the sphere)*

---

There is a suspicion that this may be a bug, related to `AxisOrigin`. Therefore, I am adding tag "bugs".

Comment: I think you need `AxesEdge` like in this question [Method -> {“AxesInFront” -> False} for Graphics3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32168/5478). But I'm not sure because you want to hide ticks behind Sphere and then you are saying that the third example is correct...

Comment: Thanks, @Kuba, it looks the question you linked could be truly useful; the third example is right, the reason is blue axis is in front of the sphere, seen from the viewer, for that particular coordinate system placement.

Comment: 1. First of all suspicion is not enough to give that Tag. 2. I don't think it is a bug. If you focus on the link I've given you will see that it is the way it is working. Axes which are not created with `AxesEdge` are different objects which will always be on top of 3D graphics...

Comment: ... and that is why I think it is a duplicate of my question.

Comment: @Kuba, AxisOrigin doesn't create new axis, only shapes it, but as well it introduces this unproper and unexpected behaviour. It's not mentioned anyhow in docs, so it really looks like a bug

Comment: @Kuba actually, I now think this may well be a duplicate of that if there is no "TicksInFront" option - I just got a little ahead of myself as the code used was not given credit where credit was due... :)

Comment: @funnypony I think it's just the things *appears to be*. The [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32231/17) under Kuba's question came from a WRI employee, thus is at least "semi-official". Actually I guess the appeared "axis" when using `AxisOrigin` or not using it are constructed from different base/origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems AxesOrigin property spoils everything. A bug maybe.. I can suggest 2 way outs:

first, simply:

```
Graphics3D[{arrowAxes[3], Sphere[{1, 1, 1}]}, Axes -> True, Boxed -> False, 
 AxesEdge -> {{0, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, -1}}, 
 AxesStyle -> Opacity[0], TicksStyle -> Opacity[1]]
```

[image]

This gives what you want, but i don't know how to specify the the axesrange explicitly

secondly and you can try draw your figures in Plot3D environment:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[0, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}, {0, 3}},
  AxesEdge -> {{0, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, -1}}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
  Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, PlotStyle -> Opacity@0, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None],
 Graphics3D[{arrowAxes[3], Sphere[{1, 1, 1}]}]]
```

(this gives the same)

Comment: This is not a bug. In every plot the axis visibility overrides the opacity setting. Evaluate `Graphics3D[Sphere[{1, 1, 1}], AxesOrigin -> {1, 1/2, 3}, Axes -> True]` and you'll realise that even though the sphere is opaque, the axes (and ticks) are still visible behind it. This is the standard. In your (@Jens's) code, you(he) *replaces* the axes with a graphics primitive (`ArrowTube`). Since graphics primitives respect opacity, he demonstrates how leaving the ticks in place, shows through the sphere but the tubed axis doesn't. As he says, the ticks can be made by hand if need be...

Comment: @gpap, no it's not standard. This problem arises ONLY when you use AxesOrigin property. Draw anything in 3D without AxeisOrigin and you'll get normal predictable behaviour, where back axis doesn't overlay objects. The AxisOrigin property introduces this unproper and unexpected behaviour. It's not mentioned anyhow in docs, so why one shouldn't consider it a bug?

Comment: This is because ONLY when you use axes origin, mathematica stops readjusting the axes according to the viewpoint.

Answer (score 2):

I just changed your code a little bit, to `TickStyle->None`

```
arrowAxes[arrowLength_] := 
  Map[{Apply[RGBColor, #], Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]]} &, 
   arrowLength IdentityMatrix[3]];

Graphics3D[{Sphere[{1, 1, 1}], arrowAxes[3]}, Axes -> True, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, AxesStyle -> Opacity[0], 
 TicksStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Jason, thanks, I appreciate this, but this hides ticks altogether... I want them where they are not hiden by the sphere