# How to eliminate tick marks, retaining tick labels, in ArrayPlot (and related functions)?

Tags: plotting

Consider the following example:

```
labels = Transpose@{Range@4, {"a", "b", "c", "d"}};
ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[1, {4, 4}],
 Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> None,
 FrameTicks -> {{labels, labels}, {labels, labels}}]
```

[image]

I want to eliminate the tick marks (the little lines that appear with the row/column labels), but retain the labels (a, b, etc.). Using `FrameTicks->None` removes the tick marks, but also removes the labels, so it's not what I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: if you want to keep ticks in the white cells you make add FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black], FrameStyle -> Directive[Black]

Answer (score 4):

Look for details on "Ticks" in help, each tick can be defined by `{x, label, len, style}` - len defines the outer and inner length of the tick, so in your case just add `0` to each tick specs:

```
labels = Transpose@{Range@4, {"a", "b", "c", "d"}, 0 Range[4]};
```

and here you go:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can use `Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}]` option.

```
labels = Transpose@{Range@4, {"a", "b", "c", "d"}}; 
ArrayPlot[RandomInteger[1, {4, 4}], Mesh -> True, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 FrameTicks -> {{labels, labels}, {labels, labels}}, 
 Method -> {"FrameInFront" -> False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trick! Never heard of such method and can't find it in docs... anyway thanks for a nice new approach!

Comment: @funnypony [32231](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32231/5478)