# How to make 3 dimensional arrows look good when their lengths are wildly different?

Tags: graphics3d

I was trying to adapt Jens's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2786/9490) for adding arrows to a 3D graphics into a general plotting function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101490/9490).  But I find that when I try to combine the `Graphics3D` object with the `Plot3D` it makes the arrows ugly when the x, y, and z axes have different length scales.  Essentially, the `Plot3D` will always have a `BoxRatio` near to `{1 ± 0.5, 1 ± 0.5, 1 ± 0.5}`

```
lengths1 = {2, 2, .1};
lengths2 = {2, 2, 2};
lengths3 = {2, 2, 100};
arrowfunc[
   lengths_] := {RGBColor @@ #, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]]} & /@ 
   DiagonalMatrix[lengths];
Graphics3D[arrowfunc@#, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}] & /@ {lengths1, 
  lengths2, lengths3}
```

[image: bad arrows]

Is there any way to modify `arrowfunc` to make these all look basically identical?  I've tried adding `Arrowheads` with a `Scaled` size, but it didn't work; likewise adding a `Scaled` radius to the `Tube` function.

Answer (score 7):

What follows is unfortunately not a completely satisfactory answer; I decided to share it because some parts of it seem to work *despite* my best efforts to understand why...

---

I am using *Mathematica* 10.3.0.0 on Win7-64bit. These are Jason's definitions:

```
lengths1 = {2, 2, .1};
lengths2 = {2, 2, 2};
lengths3 = {2, 2, 100};
```

---

**If 2D arrows are acceptable** rather than tube-based ones, then apparently setting the size by using the *symbolic* values `Small`, `Medium`, `Large` etc seems to work much better:

```
Function[{lengths},
  Graphics3D[{
      (* notice symbolic size indicator *)
      Arrowheads[Large], Thick, Red,
      Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, #}] & /@ DiagonalMatrix[lengths]
    },
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 300, 
    TicksStyle -> {Black, Black, Directive[Medium, Red]},
    (* ViewAngle is the puzzling part: why do I need this? *)
    ViewAngle -> 35 Degree
  ]
] /@ {lengths1, lengths2, lengths3}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This **does not work with 3D tube-based arrows** though.

---

The puzzling observation is in the fact that, using the exact same function but leaving out the `ViewAngle` directive, or alternatively setting it to `Automatic` or `All`, I first obtain the following graphics:

[image: ViewAngle -> All]

If I then simply *click on each of them*, or rotate them, or in any other way interact with them, then I obtain the same thing as the graphic shown above that had an explicit setting of `ViewAngle`:

[image: clicked on]

I find this behavior quite bizarre, and can offer no better explanation for it than a front-end glitch.

Comment: Thank you, this does satisfy the need for the arrows to be independent of their size, but when I try to combine them with a 3D plot, as in [this code](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=W0Wvkkxf), it becomes hard to see them.

Comment: @JasonB Perhaps try changing the color of the arrows to one that stands out better against your plot (e.g. `Blue`), and including the `ViewAngle` directive in the last `Show`, rather than in the `arrowaxisfunc`, i.e. `Show[plot, arrows,ViewAngle -> 35 Degree]` within your `threeDArrowPlot2`. Not perfect by any means, but maybe slightly better. Try also adding `Appearance -> "Projected"` within the `Arrowheads[]` directive, i.e. `Arrowheads[Large, Appearance -> "Projected"]`.