# 3D Tube with large disparity in point magnitudes

Tags: graphics3d

Consider a tube in 3D, where one of the dimensions is much flatter than the others:

```
pts = Table[{i, i, i/100.0}, {i, 1, 100}];
Graphics3D[Tube[pts]]
```

[image: flat tube]

This is fine, but a bit flat - now I want it an a square box.

```
Graphics3D[Tube[pts], BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image: bad tube]

This has gone horribly wrong. How do I get a normal looking tube? Thanks

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101495/how-to-make-3-dimensional-arrows-look-good-when-their-lenghs-are-wildly-differen

Comment: One solution I have come up with is to rescale the data points so they are of equal magnitude, and then to manually relabel the tick marks. However, this isn't really a solution

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you can't get a tube with a circular cross-section if the aspect ratio of your plot distorts circles. You will have to do some rescaling / reshaping by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to interpret the task to get a cube-shaped box around the plot:

```
cubePR[plotrange_] := 
  plotrange /. {a_, b_} :> (a + b)/2 + #/2 {-1, 1} &[
   Max[Differences /@ plotrange]];

Show[#, PlotRange -> cubePR[PlotRange@#]] &@Graphics3D[Tube[pts]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get a normal looking tube by giving it a reasonable radius (2nd argument to `Tube`).

```
pts = Table[{i, i, i/100}, {i, 1, 100}];
Graphics3D[Tube[pts, 5]]
```

[image: tube]

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Scale` with parameters that depend  on the `BoxRatios` and `PlotRange` to modify `Tube`s to look like circular independent of `BoxRatios` and `PlotRange`

```
ClearAll[scaledTube]
scaledTube[t_Tube, pr_, br_] := Scale[t, Normalize[-Subtract @@@ pr]/br, 
   Mean /@ CoordinateBounds[t[[1]]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
pts = Table[{i, i, i/100.0}, {i, 1, 100}];

tube = Graphics3D[Tube[pts, 5]]
```

[image]

```
With[{br = {1, 1, 1}, pr = {{1, 100}, {1, 100}, {0, 1}}}, 
 Labeled[Graphics3D[scaledTube[Tube[pts, 5], pr, br], 
   BoxRatios -> br, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> pr], 
  Grid[{{"box ratios: ", br}, {"plot range:", pr}}, 
   Alignment -> {Left, Center}], Top]]
```

[image]

versus what we get without scaling:

```
With[{br = {1, 1, 1}, pr = {{1, 100}, {1, 100}, {0, 1}}}, 
 Labeled[Graphics3D[Tube[pts, 5], BoxRatios -> br, Axes -> True,        
    PlotRange -> pr], 
  Grid[{{"box ratios: ", br}, {"plot range:", pr}}, 
   Alignment -> {Left, Center}], Top]]
```

[image]

```
With[{br = {1, 2, 3/2}, pr = {{1, 100}, {1, 100}, {0, 1}}}, 
 Labeled[Graphics3D[scaledTube[Tube[pts, 5], pr, br], 
   BoxRatios -> br, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> pr], 
  Grid[{{"box ratios: ", br}, {"plot range:", pr}}, 
   Alignment -> {Left, Center}], Top]]
```

[image]

versus no scaling:

[image]

If we replace `Tube[pts, 5]` with `Tube[pts]` in the first two examples above we get

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: somewhat related: [How to force the ellipsoid of BubbleChart3D to be spherical when the BoxRatios is rectangular?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/176756/125)

Answer (score 1):

We can use the option `PlotRangePadding` instead of `BoxRatios` to get a box with desired proportions without distorting `Tube`s:

```
Grid[Partition[#, 2] &[Labeled[
    Graphics3D[{Tube[pts]},  PlotRangePadding -> #, ImageSize -> 300], 
    Style[Row[{"PlotRangePadding -> ", #}], 14], Top] & /@ 
  {Automatic, 5 {1, 1, 3}, 5 {1, 1, 10}, {5, 5, 100}}], 
 Dividers -> All]
```

[image]