# How to force the ellipsoid of BubbleChart3D to be spherical when the BoxRatios is rectangular?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, charts, plot-themes

I have a `BubbleChart3D` as below, while the `BoxRatio` is rectangular:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123];
pts1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 4}];
pts2 = RandomReal[10, {10, 4}];]
BubbleChart3D[{pts1, pts2}, BoxRatios -> {0.5, 1.5, 2}]
```

[image]

As you can see, the points are ellipsoids instead of spheres. How can I force the points to become spherical again?

Many thanks!

---

Many thanks for the reply. But I may need to add a subsequent section for the question, as the situation is so odd: whenever I changed my data, the shape of the sphere can be changed from sphere back to ellipsoid.

I try to simplify my current work as below:-

```
k = 10;
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123]; pts0 = RandomReal[10, {k, 4}];]

pts1 = pts0;
pts1[[All, 1]] = pts0[[All, 1]] + (x1 = -50);
pts1[[All, 2]] = pts0[[All, 2]] + (x2 = 80);
pts1[[All, 3]] = pts0[[All, 3]] + (x3 = 200);

boxRatio1 = {0.5, 1.5, 2.7};
plotRange1 = {{-70, -30}, {60, 110}, {0, 250}};

cef[br_: {1, 1, 1}, pr_] := (dPr = Flatten@(Differences /@ pr); Scale[ChartElementData["Bubble3D"][##], MapThread[Times, {1.5/br, dPr/Min[dPr]}]] &);

bchart3b = BubbleChart3D[pts1, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> boxRatio1, ChartElementFunction -> cef[boxRatio1, plotRange1], PlotRange -> plotRange1]
```

As you can see, when `k` is 10, the shape of the points are spheres. When `k` is 9, the shape of the points are ellipsoid...

Why is that?

Comment: I've been trying to do this with post-processing but it's not going great... I can't quite figure out how to make `GeometricTransformationBox3D` do what I want.

Comment: For BubbleChart3D there is no such option BoxRatios. However, this option is used, which in itself is funny.

Comment: @AlexTrounev it's available for all `Graphics3D`-type objects

Comment: This is used, but this should be described in the options, but there is no such option for BubbleChart3D

Comment: @AlexTrounev the documentation leaves out most duplicated options. Check out: ``Options[BubbleChart3D, BoxRatios]``. It'll show you that it is, in fact, and option.

Comment: Thank you, I received a response `{BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}}`. It's news to me that some options are not described in the Options, but they are there as hidden features.

Comment: We could deform the ellipsoid to get the ball. But if we call `ChartElementData["BubbleChart3D"]`, we get the answer `{"Bubble3D", "Cone", "Cube", "Cylinder", "FadingCube", \
"GradientScaleCube", "MarkerBubble3D", "PolyhedronBubble3D", \
"ProfileCube", "SegmentScaleCube", "SquareWaveCube", \
"TriangleWaveCube"}`. There is no ellipsoid in this list. Therefore, we need to write a new code to expand the possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2:** Finding a fix for that would work for all built-in `ChartElementFunction`s seems challenging. The following modification of `cef` works only for `"Bubble3D"`. The function `addMetaData` attaches  the `MinMax` of the last column of the data and the range of bubble sizes as metadata,  and this metadata is used by `cef2` in rescaling the sphere primitives.

```
ClearAll[cef2, addMetaData]
cef2[br_: {1, 1, 1}, pr_: {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}, sc_: .1] := Module[
    {ced = ChartElementData["Bubble3D"][##], 
     rs = sc Rescale[#2[[-1]], #3[[1, 1]], #3[[1, 2]]] Norm[
        Subtract @@ Transpose[pr]] Normalize[-Subtract @@@ pr]/br},
    Replace[ced, Scale[a_, b_, c_] :> Scale[a, rs, c], {0, ∞}]] &;

addMetaData[data_, bsizes_] := data -> {MinMax[data[[All, -1]]], bsizes};

k = 9;
boxRatio1 = {0.5, 1.5, 2.7};
plotRange1 = {{-70, -30}, {60, 110}, {0, 250}};
bsizes = {0.1, .5};
Row[{BubbleChart3D[pts1, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> boxRatio1, 
   PlotRange -> plotRange1], 
  BubbleChart3D[addMetaData[pts1, bsizes], ImageSize -> 200, 
   BoxRatios -> boxRatio1, PlotRange -> plotRange1, 
   ChartElementFunction -> cef2[boxRatio1, plotRange1]]}]
```

[image]

**Update:** A custom `ChartElementFunction` that modifies the built-in ones using `Scale` to remove the distortion:

```
ClearAll[cef]
cef[br_: {1, 1, 1}][cedf_: "Bubble3D"] := Scale[ChartElementData[cedf][##], 1/br] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
br1 = {0.5, 1.5, 2};
Row[BubbleChart3D[{pts1, pts2}, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> br1, 
    ChartElementFunction -> #] & /@ {"Bubble3D", cef[br1][]}]
```

[image]

```
br2 = {3, 1, 2};
Row[BubbleChart3D[{pts1, pts2}, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> br2, 
    ChartElementFunction -> #] & /@ {"Bubble3D", cef[br2][]}]
```

[image]

```
Row[BubbleChart3D[{pts1, pts2}, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> br1, 
    ChartElementFunction -> #] & /@ {"ProfileCube", cef[br1]["ProfileCube"]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can post-process the output of `BubbleChart3D` to modify the distorted spheres. If you don't mind loosing tooltips (due to the option setting `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`), post-processing becomes easier:

```
postprocess = # /. Translate[Scale[{a_}, b_, c_], d_] :> 
 Translate[Scale[{a}, b/(BoxRatios /. Options[#, BoxRatios]), c], d] &;
```

**Example:**

```
bc3d1 = BubbleChart3D[{pts1, pts2}, BoxRatios -> {0.5, 1.5, 2}, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{bc3d1, postprocess @ bc3d1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help, and `BubbleChart3D[{pts1, pts2}, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> br1, 
 ChartElementFunction -> cef[br1][]]` works well. But when I define the PlotRange like `BubbleChart3D[{pts1, pts2}, ImageSize -> 200, BoxRatios -> br1, ChartElementFunction -> cef[br1][], PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 40}}]`, the distortion appears again... How can I combine the change for both `BoxRatios` and `PlotRange` into `cef`?

Comment: @HMC, good catch.  I will update with a fix.

Comment: thanks. I amended my question to append my previous work on `cef`. You may use that to save effort. Thanks.

Comment: @HMC, does the version in update 2 work in your version/os?

Comment: I just saw the editions you've made 2 days ago, sorry. I will edit it back to my current codes and tested for the several situations previously having problems, and will revert. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. The ellipsoids become spherical. But the sizes of the spheres become identical, instead of using the 4th column of the data as size. Is it possible to make a change? I still have no idea why my original method of `cef2` doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I think I know why. I will fix it in a moment.