# 3D arrow built with Tube distorted when it is combined with a 3D plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I am trying to place a 3D arrow in a `Plot3D`:

```
g[x_, y_] := 1/(2*π*σ^2)*E^(-((x^2 + y^2)/(2*σ^2))) /. {σ -> 1};
Show[
  Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, g[0, 0]}, {1, 1, g[0, 0]}}]]}]]
```

But the problem is that this results in a very squeezed arrow:

[image: Squeezed arrow]

I think it has something to do with the different scaling at the z-axis but I don't know how to overcome that (without scaling the original function). Adding the option `BoxRatios -> Automatic` to the show command makes the arrow look normal but then the plot reduces to a flat surface:
[image: Arrow normal but surface is now flat]

Related question but without a satisfactory answer for 3D arrows: [How to make 3 dimensional arrows look good when their lenghs are wildly different?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101495/how-to-make-3-dimensional-arrows-look-good-when-their-lenghs-are-wildly-differen)

So, any ideas of how to place a 3D arrow in a 3D plot without messing one of the graphics up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding a little bit on Michael's nice answer:

```
 g[x_, y_] := 
   1/(2*\[Pi]*\[Sigma]^2)*E^(-((x^2 + y^2)/(2*\[Sigma]^2))) /. {\[Sigma] -> 1}
```

This seems to work in most cases (different ranges, boxratios and graphics primitives):

```
scale[pl_] :=
 #/Max[#] &[-Subtract @@@ #[[1]]/#[[2]] &[
   Values /@ AbsoluteOptions[pl, {PlotRange, BoxRatios}]]]

With[{z = g[0, 0]},
 Show[
  pl = Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
    ImageSize -> Large,
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, z + 0.02}},
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5],
    PlotPoints -> 60],
  Graphics3D[
   Scale[
    {
     Red, Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 2, z}}],
     Rotate[Arrow@Tube[{{0, 0, z}, {1, 2, z}}], 90 Degree, {0, 0, 1}],
     Green, Sphere[{0, 0, z}, 0.3],
     },
    scale@pl]]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice;  this is exactly the refinement I was envisioning in my answer.  I would recommend that the OP choose this as the accepted answer rather than mine.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Scale` to "squeeze" the tube back into something resembling the correct shape:

```
Show[Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 
     Graphics3D[Scale[{Red, Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, g[0, 0]}, {1, 1, g[0, 0]}}]]}, 
                        0.3*{5, 5, 0.2}, {0, 0, g[0, 0]}]], 
     ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {0, 0.2}]
```

[image]

The first list in `Scale` (`0.3*{5, 5, 0.2}`) are the rescaling factors in the `x`, `y`, and `z` directions respectively.  I simply tweaked these until it "looked right", which is a bit kludgey;  this method could be improved by automatically detecting the size of the plot and adjusting these numbers accordingly.  The second list in `Scale` (`{0, 0, g[0, 0]}`) tells Mathematica to leave this point fixed in the rescaling;  you will presumably want to leave the basepoint of the arrow fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to abandon `Tube`, which only works well the box ratios are `{1, 1, 1}`, and fall back on using a thick line.

```
g[x_, y_] := 1/(2 π σ^2) E^(-((x^2 + y^2)/(2 σ^2))) /. {σ -> 1};

Show[
  Plot3D[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]],
  Graphics3D[
    {Red, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[.04], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, g[0, 0]}, {1, 1, g[0, 0]}}]}]]
```

[image: plot]