# How to do this 3D grid drawing?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

The idea is to make axes 3d, with a more subdued in black mesh, and shafts with their respective numbers with a maximum of 10 in each (black to print after the size of half a sheet craft, vine also print two per page )

z in the second drawing up

(mathematica ver 10.0.1.0 64 bits)

[image: example 1]
[image: example 2]

Comment: [`FaceGrids`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FaceGrids.html) doesn't exactly reproduce your plot, but it could be just what you need.

Comment: I just want the coordinate axes so that these kids can practice in 3D drawings, without box

Comment: Closely related, maybe duplicate: [Arrows on axes in Plot3D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2785/245). I don't understand what the second plot in the question is for. Is the grid desired, or only the arrows? This would be much clearer if you posted the code you have already tried.

Comment: You kindly put a similar first example, I do not drive much with the graphics instructions yet.

Answer (score 5):

Well, maybe you can make something with this?

```
a1 := SliceContourPlot3D[z, 
  x == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, Background -> Black, 
  ContourShading -> White, Contours -> 9, 
  TicksStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]
a2 := SliceContourPlot3D[z, 
  y == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, ContourShading -> White,
   Contours -> 9]
b1 := SliceContourPlot3D[x, 
  y == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, ContourShading -> White,
   Contours -> 9]
b2 := SliceContourPlot3D[x, 
  z == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, ContourShading -> White,
   Contours -> 9]
c1 := SliceContourPlot3D[y, 
  x == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, ContourShading -> White,
   Contours -> 9]
c2 := SliceContourPlot3D[y, 
  z == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, ContourShading -> White,
   Contours -> 9]
p := Graphics3D[{PointSize -> 0.05, Point[{3, 2, 2}], Red, 
   Arrowheads[0.1], Thick, Line[{{0, 2, 2}, {3, 2, 2}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 5}, {3, 0, 5}}], Green, Line[{{3, 0, 2}, {3, 2, 2}}],
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 5}, {0, 3, 5}}], Blue, Line[{{3, 2, 0}, {3, 2, 2}}],
    Arrow[{{5, 0, 0}, {5, 0, 3}}]}]
```

And...

```
Show[a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, p]
```

[image]

By using variables instead of constants you can quickly change the position of the point.

Comment: error 

Show::gcomb: Could not combine the graphics objects in Show[SliceContourPlot3D[z,x==0,{x,-5,5},{y,-5,5},{z,-5,5},Background->\!\(\*
GraphicsBox[{
{GrayLevel[0], RectangleBox[{0, 0}]}, 
{GrayLevel[0], RectangleBox[{1, -1}]}, 
{GrayLevel[0], RectangleBox[{0, -1}, {2, 1}]}},
AspectRatio->1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: @zeros Are you using the latest edition of `Mathematica`? Maybe try quitting kernel

Comment: Considering the form of the error message, the OP is likely not using 10.2. @zeros, please include your version number in your question.

Comment: mathematica ver 10.0.1.0 64 bits

Answer (score 4):

Tricks to my mind,Suppose your version is 10.2 or later,although I don't sure you will like

```
Show[SliceContourPlot3D[#, 
    "CenterPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
    ContourShading -> White] & /@ {x, y, z}, Axes -> True, 
 Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: error Show::gcomb: "Could not combine the graphics objects in \!\(Show[{SliceContourPlot3D[x, \"CenterPlanes\", {x, \(-2\), 2}, {y, \(-2\), 2}, {z, \(-2\), 2}, ColorFunction -> \((White &)\)], SliceContourPlot3D[y, \"CenterPlanes\", {x, \(-2\), 2}, {y, \(-2\), 2}, {z, \(-2\), 2}, ColorFunction -> \((White &)\)], SliceContourPlot3D[z, \"CenterPlanes\", {x, \(-2\), 2}, {y, \(-2\), 2}, {z, \(-2\), 2}, ColorFunction -> \((White &)\)]}, Axes -> True, <<1>>, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]\). "

Comment: @zeros Which version are you using?

Comment: mathematica  ver 10.0.1.0      64 bits

Comment: @zeros `SliceContourPlot3D` is introduced in version 10.2