# Creating custom schematics with mathematica

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to produce the following schematic

[image]

A starting code

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a1 = Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.025], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}];
a2 = Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {-2, 0}}]}];
a3 = Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.025], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {0, 2}}]}];
a4 = Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.025], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-1.5, -1}}]}];
a5 = Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {1.5, 1}}]}];
p1 = ListPlot[{{-1.1, -0.72}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.4], PointSize[0.045]}];
p2 = ListPlot[{{ 1.1, 0.72}}, 
     PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0.4], PointSize[0.045]}]; 
Show[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, p1, p2}, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image]

I can also easily insert all the text. My problem is how to insert the twisted arrow around the z axis. Any ideas?

Comment: `Graphics` `Graphics3D` `DrawingTools`?

Comment: @Kuba A good starting example would be nice. In particular, how to draw the arrows at the end of the axes and also the curved arrow around the z-axis.

Comment: I think this is too broad.  Please start by learning how to build graphics from primitives, then ask specific questions about the points where you get stuck.  See here for axes with arrows: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11606/12 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2785/12

Comment: The curved arrow will need to be done from scratch.  Use a `Table` to create the set of coordinates manually, and put them in `Arrow`.

Comment: related: [2785](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2785/5478)

Comment: I think broad guidelines would be in order, so you know that you are on the right track: 1. build everything from graphics primitives and put them in a `Graphics3D`.  The axes need to be done manually too if we want arrowheads, use `Arrow`.  Use `Dashed` or `Dotted` directives for those appearances. For lines, `Line`.  For text, `Text`.  Use `Background -> White` in `Text` to make it obscure the line behind like with $r_1$. Use `Sphere[]` for the balls, $P_1, P_2$. The curved arrow will be a *single* `Arrow` primitive.  Use the `Arrowheads` directive to control the arrow size.

Comment: " My problem is the arrows." Use `Arrow` instead of `Line`, and use the `Arrowheads` directive to specify their size. Instead of `ListPlot`, use `Point` and the `PointSize` directive.   Normally one would put everything in a single `Graphics` instead of combining multiple ones with `Show`.  Since this is really 3D, you can consider `Graphics3D` instead.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks! Please, see my edit.

Comment: `ellipse = 
  Graphics[Rotate[Circle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}, {135*Degree, 405*Degree}], 
    0*Degree]]; 
arrow = Graphics[{Arrowheads[Medium], 
    Arrow[{{2*Cos[45*Degree], 
       Sin[45*Degree]}, {2*Cos[45*Degree] - 0.12, 
       Sin[45*Degree] + 0.07}}]}]; 
plot = Show[ellipse, arrow]` The values of `0.12` and `0.07` are a result of trial and error; this can be made automatic using a tangent but I don't have the time now. I'll look at this again later.

Comment: @corey979 It seems to work. But how can I adjust the size of the twisted arrow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've created this:

```
TwistArrow[pos_List, ab_List] := 
 Module[{ellipse, arrow, pos1 = pos[[1]], pos2 = pos[[2]], 
   a = ab[[1]], b = ab[[2]]},
  ellipse = 
   Graphics[
    Rotate[Circle[pos, {a, b}, {135 Degree, 405 Degree}], 0 Degree]]; 
  arrow = Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.015], 
     Arrow[{{a Cos[45 Degree] + pos1, 
        b Sin[45 Degree] + pos2}, {a Cos[45*Degree] + pos1 - 0.06, 
        b Sin[45*Degree] + pos2 + 0.035}}]}]; 
  plot = Show[ellipse, arrow]
  ]
```

which gives (`plot1` is the figure `Show`ed in the question)

```
Show[plot1,TwistArrow[{0, 1}, 0.1 {2, 1}]]
```

[image]

`pos_List={0,1}` is the location of the center of the `ellipse`, and `ab_List=0.1 {2,1}` are the major and minor axis of the `ellipse` (or semi-axis?). The other parameters, i.e. all angles, size of the arrow (`Arrowheads[0.015]`) and the positioning (`-0.06` and `+0.035`) were chosen for this particular problem. One can put them all as arguments of the function, but I think it's easiest to just fiddle with the parameters to find the right ones.

Comment: It works like a charm! Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at SciDraw at http://scidraw.nd.edu/. Lots of support for many kinds of figures.

Comment: Looks interesting.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau It's one of the largest and most carefully designed free packages that I am aware of.  The biggest strength is creating multipanel figures. Drawbacks are performance and the fact that it is quite different from standard Mathematica, so it takes a while to learn.