# Can we modify the axes in Plot3D as shown?

Tags: plotting

I am trying a 3D plot `Plot3D[{ x^2 y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic,  ImageSize -> 300]`. However, instead of conventional plotstyle, I need something like following with only three bold axes are and not the box:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated**

```
Clear[plot, arrowhead, axies]; 
plot = 
 Plot3D[{x^2 y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 300, 
  Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> {{1}, {1}, {1}}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive["Label", 14, Thick, Blue], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Blue, FontFamily -> Times, 15], 
  AxesStyle -> Opacity[1], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}];
arrowhead = 
  Graphics[Polygon[{{-1, 1/4}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/4}, {-1, 1/4}}]];
axies = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 
       Automatic, {arrowhead, 1}}}], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.2, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.2, 0}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.2}}], 
    Text[Style[O, Blue, 20, FontFamily -> Times], {0, 0, 0}, {1, 1}]}];
Show[plot, axies, ViewPoint -> {-3, -2, 1}, PlotRange -> All, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

**Original**

According to the picture,we need to construct a plan arrow instead of a space arrow.

```
plot = Plot3D[{x^2 y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
arrowhead = 
  Graphics[Polygon[{{-1, 1/4}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/4}, {-1, 1/4}}]];
axies = Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 
      Automatic, {arrowhead, 1}}}], AbsoluteThickness[4], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {1.2, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1.2, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1.2}}]}]; 
Show[axies, plot, ViewPoint -> {-3, -2, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but how to put those ticks: 0 at origin, and 1 at the end of three axes? And I actually need it without boxed, and that I understand can be done by Boxed->False.

Comment: @User101 see the updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}`, is that what you want?

Comment: It doesn't give those nice axes that I am looking for.

Comment: Oh! To give this format you will need to use Arrowheads, but unfortunately, in 3D plots, it's more complicated. Maybe here you find a way: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/arrows-on-axes-in-plot3d